# How to move an image in a circular motion without rotating it?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have a sun image and moon images on my website which will be, for the majority of the day be hidden but when it is their time to show, they will be going in a circular motion starting from the left and finishing to the right.

I have code which says how much percent through the day or night it is to be implement, I just need to know how I can move the image in a circular motion without rotating the image at all.

Comment: as far as i understand your requirement, this has nothing to do with php, so retagging with javascript and html

Comment: Well all the calculations are done in PHP to find out the users sunrise and sunset times and them to calculate the percentage they are through the night or day so I thought I would have to tell the image where it needs to be via PHP too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css part:

1. set the css position to absolute
2. set the x and y coordinates (css top and left) according to trigonometry

Trigonometry:

basically you want to go half a circle,  pi degrees at 0% and zero degrees at 100%, so its like getting circle coordinates (ie. x=center+radius*cos(angle))  but the only complicated part is that you need to reverse the angle:   PI*(1-percent)

```
var centerX = document.body.offsetWidth / 2;   // center of screen
var centerY = document.body.offsetHeight / 2;
var radiusX = document.body.offsetWidth / 3;   // radius 1/3 screen
var radiusY = document.body.offsetHeight / 3;
var angle = Math.PI * (1-percent);
var x = centerX + radiusX * Math.cos(angle);
var y = centerY + radiusY * Math.sin(angle);
```

Comment: I cannot distinguish between languages, is this Javascript or PHP and how do I use this to edit the CSS/Image?

Comment: If you cannot distinguish the languages then I think you may need a beginners book or course and not specific programming questions...  If you are not committed to PHP I recommend https://www.udacity.com/course/cs253

Comment: The code is javascript (note it uses the width and height of the screen - which aren't available on the server-side).  You can perhaps do the same calculations in PHP and use percents instead of pixel coordinates,  eg.   x = 50 + 33*cos(angle)  but remember that to use css absolute position with percents you need the container element to be position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

I just figured out circular motion for myself and it's pretty simple. You take a radius, an angle, and some simple math and determine the position of something. So...

```
var body   = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
    radius = 100, // Some radius here
    max    = 50;  // max number of generations we want (half a circle)
for (var i = 1; i <= max * 2; i++) {
    var div                   = document.createElement("div"),
        angle                 = Math.PI * (i / max);
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    div.style.borderRadius    = div.style.height = div.style.width = "8px";
    div.style.left            = ((Math.sin(angle) * radius) + radius) + "px";
    div.style.position        = "absolute";
    div.style.top             = ((Math.cos(angle) * radius) + radius) + "px";
    body.appendChild(div);
}
```

And you should get a full circle. Just de- and reconstruct the math as needed and you should be good to go.